# When exporting Excel to CSV, formatted numbers are different?

Tags: excel, csv

So I have an excel file that added quotation marks around the values in all my column using Format Cells and added `\"@\"`. In Excel, it looks like it's suppose to, BUT when I export to CSV and open it in a .txt file, instead of "BOB", I get """BOB"""

Why is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Comment: It's happening to differentiate actual quotation marks in a string from quotation marks inserted in the CSV to prevent commas in strings from separating a string into two different fields. Nothing is broken, nothing needs to be fixed.

Comment: so how would I get my csv file to show "BOB" instead of """BOB"""?

Comment: You don't. Any half decent software that can interpret CSVs will take these quotes into account. This looks more and more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Is there an actual problem trying to accomplish something with the file? If yes, what are you trying to accomplish and what, exactly is the problem you encountered?